# sed match at specific column in text file?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I have to import some data from printed reports into a form that can be used to migrate to another system. I seem to be stuck on one little pattern: I am trying to delete any lines that have the string .00 starting at column 128 in the report, along with the following line.

I'm using the following :`sed '/^\{128\}\.00/,+1 d'inputfile >outputfile`

I'm using FreeBSD and I'm getting the RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid. I get the same error if I experiment by removing the +1 to delete the following line, so I imagine I'm missing something more basic.

(I'm sure that someone will jump in and say "You should use awk, Like this..." but I have specific reasons for trying to do this using sed. And, unfortunately, it has been 30+ years since I was a sed/awk wizard and I'm just as rusty at both of them. 8-) )

Thank you for your help.

This is a two-line example of the text I am trying to  match:

```
1011-000                                       .00                  .00                .00                .00                  .00
Petty Cash-Shop
```

Notice that, despite the line-wrapping here, the last column is .00 . I got the column numbers from experimenting in vim. I expect both of these lines to disappear once I execute the sed command.

I changed the command to `sed '/\.\{128\}\.00/,+1 d'inputfile >outputfile`and they do not disappear. (But thanks for catching that "."that was needed. I no longer get the RE error.)

Comment: Your `{128}` quantifier modifies `^`, which makes no sense. Use `.{128}` instead (or correctly escaped `.\{128\}`)

Comment: There is nothing before `\{128\}`, what do you want 128 of?

Comment: What separates "columns"? Spaces, commas, tabs, something else? Or do you mean "character position"? Whatever your reason for wanting to use sed is a bad one, unless maybe the "a", "w", and "k" keys are broken on your keyboard. sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. You are not doing that so this is not a job for sed, it's a job for awk, as your computer is currently telling you by demonstrating the non-portable nature of using sed for something like this.

Comment: @EdMorton: I think that "column" means "position" here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte his code is written as if that's the case but his code doesn't work so rather than possibly wasting time on a solution to a problem the OP doesn't have IMHO it's best to just ask to be sure. An example with concise, testable, sample input and expected output (i.e. a [mcve]) would help too.

Comment: I'm on track now, thank you. It still doesn't work but now that I change it to:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/^.\{127\}\.00/{N;d;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

If next string after 127th character is `.00`, then add next line to the pattern space using the `N` command, and deletes it using `d`.

Comment: That gave me an error: "extra characters at the end of the d command". However, I may be coming across a problem from differences between BSD sed and Linux/GNU sed. Thanks for the help.